# The bootstrap dropdown doesn't pop up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a dropdown menu in Bootstrap in HTML. The button appears and so does the caret. But the menu doesnt pop up. Here is my code:

```css
.dropdown {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.dropdown .btn-default {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.dropdown .btn-default,
.dropdown .btn-default:focus {
  background-color: coral;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown .btn-default:active,
.dropdown .btn-default .dropdown-toggle:active,
.dropdown .btn-default:hover {
  background-color: coral;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown">
  Lingua
  <button class=" btn btn-default " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="dropdwn_img" src="http://64.64.216.18/images/photos/italy-flag.png">Italiano
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="http://64.64.216.18/images/photos/italy-flag.png">Italia</li>
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="http://www.geysir-andernach.de/navigation2012/flag_2.png">England</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is something  I've done wrong or should I change something  there? Thanks!
The answer below really helped but I have 2 dropdown buttons and the menu of each of them appears under the first dropdown button. How can I fix that?
Here are the 2 dropdowns:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown">
  Lingua
  <button class=" btn btn-default " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italiano
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia</li>
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">England</li>
  </ul>

  Paese
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia</li>
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">England</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/L0c03u7d/ ! Can you post the error from `Console`

Comment: Your code is working fine..you seem to have missed the jquery.js or bootstrap.js file..

Comment: Or copy paste this code in your head tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to close the dropdown and create a new dropdown.

Add below code before the text **Paese**

```
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
```

Note: You seem to be missing the `bootstrap` and `jQuery` references. Add below references to the head section of your HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Working code:**

```css
.dropdown {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown .btn-default {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.dropdown.btn-default,
.dropdown.btn-default:focus {
  background-color: coral;
  color: black;
}
.dropdown.btn-default:active,
.dropdown.btn-default.dropdown-toggle:active,
.dropdown.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: coral;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  Lingua
  <button class=" btn btn-default " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italiano
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia</li>
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">England</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  Paese
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">Italia</li>
    <li>
      <img class="dropdwn_img" src="images/flag.png">England</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but i need the buttons in the same row

Comment: @Doe : Add `display: inline-block;` to your CSS for `.dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

First try adding the reference files either from CDN or locally from your system.